# Ability to set a colour within code using a Style item, therefore not needing to concern myself with the current application theme

Tags: java, c#, android, xamarin.android

I've got a light and dark theme in my application, where I've a set of color attributes per theme in Styles.xml, for example:

```
  <style name="LightTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- colours -->
    <item name="colour_text">@color/ltext</item>
    <item name="colour_text_subtle">@color/ltext_subtle</item>
    <item name="colour_text_more_subtle">@color/ltext_more_subtle</item>
  </style>

  <!-- Dark -->
  <style name="DarkTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <!-- colours -->
    <item name="colour_text">@color/dtext</item>
    <item name="colour_text_subtle">@color/dtext_subtle</item>
    <item name="colour_text_more_subtle">@color/dtext_more_subtle</item>
  </style>
```

These colours are defined in Colours.xml, such as:

```
  <color name="ltext">#000</color>
  <color name="ltext_subtle">#8000</color>
  <color name="ltext_more_subtle">#4000</color>
  <color name="dtext">#FFF</color>
  <color name="dtext_subtle">#FAFAFA</color>
  <color name="dtext_more_subtle">#FEFEFE</color>
```

Is there a way from within code to assign a colour to a widget attribute via a Styles.xml's attribute's name? For example, I want to give a TextView the subtle text colour by telling it to be coloured "colour_text_subtle", rather than needing to check what the current theme is and then telling it to be coloured "ltext_subtle". At the moment, how I've structured things enables me to assign colours within xml without needing to concern myself about the currently selected theme, and I'm hoping to achieve similar when working with colours in code.

I'm working in Xamarin.Android, but happy to be provided general Java Android guidance on the matter leaving for me to figure out how to accomplish similar in C#.

Comment: Are you trying to achieve sort of a global theme for your controls?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean exactly, but the light and dark themes aim to provide the colours for all app controls/layouts.

Comment: Like you want a style that can make for eg a set of widgets have one common style and another set of widgets have another